How to implement @RolesAllowed functionality for Microprofile Messaging?
I haven't seen any articles on this topic, so I'm wondering how would I secure my methods when using @Incoming and @Outgoing in a Quarkus application?
In a regular REST application I'd use the @RolesAllowed, but that doesn't work when doing Messaging with RabbitMQ, etc?
I am surprised that no videos talk about making sure only certain groups/roles can actually execute the code when an event is received from an event bus. I'm not talking about who can actually connect to the server, but who can execute code in a message receiver method.
Is this a valid request? or does everyone assume an API gateway will take care of everything INTO the system and not care about security between services BEHIND the gateway?
I'm just thinking about any potential roque employees, etc.. not that we have any but always thinking "what-if"
I'm assuming to support it, we'd need to pass in a JWT token and manually validate it in the request event message or something like that.
Thanks!

This is usually enforced on the message broker connection with access rights to topics or queues. Once connected with the desired authorization level, applications can produce and consume messages within their rights. That is the security between services behind the gateway.
Even if you are doing request-reply, through a message broker, I think you'd control access on the client endpoint, not on the producer with per-request checks. There might be cases where you'd like to extract authorization from the client's request and decide whether it can lead to sending a message to a target or not.
For consumers, incoming messages aren't received inside a client request scope, so you'd need to apply a custom filter that's also very specific to the messaging technology.
